# Unable to perform functions on google sheets data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that pulls in data from different endpoints from an API.
The script then puts the data in a google sheet.  In this sheet I want to chart the data or perform a math/sum operation.  I am able to do this with the data from one endpoint just fine.  But the other endpoints (using the same code) does not allow me to do this.  I can do =A1+A2 and the value will add.  But if I try to do =sum(A1:A2) the result is 0. No matter what I do.  I am able to do the sum() operation on the other endpoint.  Its very peculiar.

Here is some of the code from my apps script:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl, params);
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var rows = [], jsondata;

for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    jsondata = json[i];
    rows.push([jsondata.currency, jsondata.amount, jsondata.fee, jsondata.date]);
  }

  return rows;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work! Wow, so whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with number formats, change the cells by highlighting them go to 'Format' -> 'Number' -> 'Automatic' and then it will work with `=SUM(A1:A2)`

To fix this issue in your script, use `.setNumberFormat('0')` on the range to set the format you require. The number format may need to be '0.00' if you are working with decimals.

Comment: Sorry but that was not what the issue seems to be.  I set everything to automatic last night but its just not working.

Comment: If some other part of your script in inserting or appending data then it could still be in the incorrect format. i.e. setting the column to automatic then appending a row with a text format in that column will ignore the previous automatic setting. After that it may be best to provide a sample sheet that can be used to replicate the problem.

Comment: Ok, I went to implement your solution but it gives me an error that says I do not have permission to use setNumberFormat

Comment: This must be a custom function? Is the JSON data in the correct format when it is pushed to the rows array?

Comment: It is a custom function and no I do not know how to format it properly in that case.  However, I am using 3-different custom functions. 1-of those functions returns everything as being formatted correctly and I can apply a function like sum() to it.  but the other two I cannot.  And I cant distinguish it in the code.

Comment: Provide a sample spreadsheet with some dummy data, it's very time consuming if not almost impossible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Im pulling in data from an external API then returning those values to my spreadsheet.